# How to use #ifndef #define #endif properly in C++

Tags: c++, include, compiler-errors

I'm working on a project where I need the following structure:
[image]

The 2 CPP files contain classes, those classes need naked functions that are in H File 1. The classes and the nakeds need variables in H File 2.

I can split the CPP files so that they use 2 separate file that contain the nakes and the variables they need. But I prefer to use this structure.

It looks like that the compiler skips the #ifndef command, I made a test for the problem:

Main:

```
#include <iostream>

//1>CPPFile2.obj : error LNK2005: "bool Test1" (?Test1@@3_NA) already defined in CPPFile1.obj
//1>CPPFile2.obj : error LNK2005: "bool Test2" (?Test2@@3_NA) already defined in CPPFile1.obj

int main()
{
}
```

CPPFile 1:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "HFile1.h"
```

CPPFile 2:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "HFile2.h"
```

HFile 1:

```
#include "HFile2.h"

#pragma once
#ifndef Name1
#define Name1

//Use test1, this workes fine
//Use test2, this workes fine

#endif
```

HFile 2:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef Name2
#define Name2

bool Test1 = false;
bool Test2 = false;

#endif
```

How is it possible that the #ifndef #define #endif structure doesn’t work properly?

Comment: Usually you don't need to make those include guards, because you already have #pragma once.

Comment: I added them in case of #pragma once is not supported, but without one of the 2 it still doesn't work.

Comment: You're violating One definition rule. You need to make `Test1` and `Test2` either `static` or `extern`.

Comment: I can see some other issues, indeed. How does HFile 1 use Test1 and Test2? With functions? Remember that your CPPFile1 will not be able to access Test1 and Test2 without an inclusion of HFile2. Unless you are using an `extern` declaration in HFile1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that the second header is *defining* the variables, not just *declaring* them. There must be a single *definition* in the program and thus compilation fails. This is unrelated to include guards, as include guards only protect within a single translation unit. In your case, each one of the .cpp files includes the header and thus define the same variables separately.

The solution would be to only *declare* the variables in the header and define them in a *single* translation unit:

```
#ifndef Name2
#define Name2
extern bool Test1;
extern bool Test2;
#endif
// single .cpp
bool Test1 = false;
bool Test2 = false;
```

Although there is some code smell around the whole thing. You might want to *redesign* your solution. The use of global variables is in most cases not a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting a *linking* error; this has nothing to do with include guards. You have defined `Test1` and `Test2` in both object files. Instead, you'll need to ensure that only one object file *defines* it and the other `extern`s it.

Answer (score 1):

Never define a variable in a header.. you should define it in a .cpp, and then if you want to access it from another .cpp file create a header with 'extern' on it.

File1.cpp

```
bool Test1 = false; //define a var in your .cpp
```

File1.h

```
extern bool Test1; //extern it in your header
```

File2.cpp

```
#include "File1.h" //include the header of the variable

void Somefunction()
{
    if (Test1) //use the variable
    {
    //someting 
    }

}
```

However it is usually a bad practice to use global variables...